# net core 3.1 dep inj error in simple scenario, ILogger bonus question

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, ilogger

I'm having trouble getting basic DI to work in my core 3.1 project. My class has a parameterless constructor yet I'm getting this error when my controller method is called: Could not create an instance of type 'NRA_Courses.Interfaces.ICourseRunner'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.
Note, I even added an empty constructor to make it explicit. What have I overlooked?

```
    public interface ICourseRunner
    {
        void StartCourse();

        void PauseCourse();

        public ICourse Course { get; set; }
        public IStudent Student { get; set; }
    }

// Implementing class
    public class CourseRunner : ICourseRunner
    {
        public ICourse Course { get; set; }
        public IStudent Student { get; set; }

        private Timer _timer => new Timer();

        private DateTime _timeStarted;
        private TimeSpan _timeRunAfterPauses;

        public CourseRunner()
        {}

        public void StartCourse()
        {
           // implemented
        }

        public void PauseCourse()
        {
           // implemented
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           // implemented
        }
    }


// Method in a controller where I want ICourseRunner injected
        public void StartCourseTimer(CourseList courseStarted, ICourseRunner courseRunner)
        { ...}
```

Bonus question, why can't I inject logging into a simple class like this? This code results in a compile error on a line where I try to do "= new Student()" because Student doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. I assume this is another gimmee:

```
    public class Student : IStudent
    {
        ...
        private readonly ILogger<Student> _logger;

        public Student(ILogger<Student> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Mucho gracias! I have spent time researching and am only asking because of a tight deadline.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs of Asp.Net Core controllers, controllers should use injection via constructor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0.
In your case, you are trying to inject the dependency via a method parameter, which may not work correctly. If you inject it via constructor (like in your example with Student), everything should work fine.

Answer for bonus question - the error's message gives all necessary information - you can't create an instance of Student via parameterless constructor just because your class doesn`t have one. The only one constructor there - with one parameter "ILogger logger". If you want to create an instance of Student via constructor - you should pass the instance of the logger to it. Another way - inject it via a DI container, which will pass all necessary dependencies for you.